# Ruby-Thin server crashes randomly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, azure

I had put a Ruby on Rails application on an Azure server(Ubuntu 64 bit). I had installed Nginx and Thin as our web server and application server respectively. Today my Thin server crashed and my site went down. I checked the log but could not find anything suspicious.

This is a snippet from my thin log:

```
 Using rack adapter
            SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
            This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
            provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
            cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
            future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

      Called from: /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/thin:23:in `load'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Error during failsafe response: Missing template index/getkey, application/getkey with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:gif, "image/*"], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/webuser/apps/production/app/views"

  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  /home/webuser/apps/production/app/controllers/index_controller.rb:97:in `getkey'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2157135730694343981__process_action__1990300394974926863__callbacks'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:76:in `render_exception'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/thin:23:in `load'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
>> Writing PID to tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid
>> Using rack adapter
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
```

My Index controller:

```
require "openssl"
require 'digest/sha2'
require 'base64'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
class IndexController < ApplicationController

  def index

    if params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Home' or params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/home'
      redirect_to "#{root_url}", :status => :moved_permanently
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Tv-Listings'
      @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/TVGuideDetailed?call=TVGuideDetailed&apikey=8a1e808b55fde9455cb3d8857ed88389&context=applicationname=sourcebits;headendid=2645&programmeimagesize=Large&channelimagesize=Large&Imagesize=Large&channelgenre=all&dateselected=0&mode=getTVGuideInfo&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&starthour=0&totalhrdata=24"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Movies' or params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/movies'
      fromdatetime = Time.now.year.to_s + "-" + Time.now.month.to_s + "-" + Time.now.day.to_s  + "+12:16"
      todatetime =  Time.now.year.to_s + "-" + Time.now.month.to_s + "-" + (Time.now + 4.day).day.to_s + "+23:59"
      @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/AllMovies?call=AllMovies&apikey=dd45045f8c68db9f54e70c67048d32e8&pageno=1&context=applicationname=website;headendid=2645&fromdatetime=#{fromdatetime}&todatetime=#{todatetime}&productionstartyear=2004&productionendyear=2015&programmeimagesize=xxlarge&castname=&isfavMovies=false&mode=getAllMovies&noCache=1389683687038&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Videos' or params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/videos'
      @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/VideosByFilter?call=VideosByFilter&apikey=53adaf494dc89ef7196d73636eb2451b&pageno=1&context=headendid=2645;applicationname=website&filtertype=popular&channelname=&videogenre=&programmeImageSize=xxlarge&mode=getAllVideos&noCache=1389685706035&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Channels' or params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/channels'
      @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/FeaturedProgramme?call=FeaturedProgramme&apikey=06138bc5af6023646ede0e1f7c1eac75&programmeimagesize=xxlarge&channelimagesize=xxlarge&imagesize=xxlarge&applicationname=website&operatorid=0&context=headendid=2645;applicationname=website&mode=featuredProgramme&pageno=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
      @popular = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/HybridChannels?call=HybridChannels&apikey=fa83a11a198d5a7f0bf77a1987bcd006&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&languageid=0&channelimagesize=small&context=headendid%3D0%3Bapplicationname%3Dwebsite&hybridgenre=Popular&mode=filterByHybridGenre"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Mobile-Apps' or params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/apps'
      @testimonials = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/AppTestimonials?call=AppTestimonials&apikey=1fc214004c9481e4c8073e85323bfd4b&pageno=1&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&appid=1&mode=getAppTestimonials&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] =~ /\/actor(.*)/
      actorname = CGI::escape(params['_escaped_fragment_'].split("/").last.gsub(/CeNc/,"$#*!").gsub(/DqO/, '"').gsub(/PLus/, '+').gsub(/ObR/, '[').gsub(/CbR/, ']').gsub(/AtR/, '@').gsub(/EmPe/, '&').gsub(/HaSh/, '#').gsub(/StAr/, '*').gsub("-", " ").gsub("~", "-").gsub("$", "/").gsub(/DoLr/, "$").gsub("*", "?").gsub("PeRc", "%"))
      result = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/CastIDByName?call=CastIDByName&apikey=bdf3f54642b2d80f8e87b6474eaaad11ece8058a&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&castname=#{actorname}&mode=getActorId&pageno=1"))
      result = result["getcastid"]["castidbyname"]["castid"]
      @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/CastDetails?apikey=375f9609c9962cce0ad6ccaaabd80362ecd2b07f&responseformat=json&responselanguage=english&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&castid=#{result}"))
      @similaractors = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/SimilarCasts?call=SimilarCasts&apikey=731df0fc93417f72fcb56f09cd754f9382ae6373&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&userid=1&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&castid=#{result}&mode=SimilarActor&pageno=1"))
      @acotsmovie = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/CastProgrammesByGenre?call=CastProgrammesByGenre&apikey=0ad54e429b2b6238550f24701541130b978e4640&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&genre=film&imagesize=medium&pageno=1&userid=1&castid=#{result}&mode=MoviesByActor&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] =~ /\/program(.*)/
      programename = CGI::escape(params['_escaped_fragment_'].split("/").last.gsub(/CeNc/,"$#*!").gsub(/DqO/, '"').gsub(/PLus/, '+').gsub(/ObR/, '[').gsub(/CbR/, ']').gsub(/AtR/, '@').gsub(/EmPe/, '&').gsub(/HaSh/, '#').gsub(/StAr/, '*').gsub("-", " ").gsub("~", "-").gsub("$", "/").gsub(/DoLr/, "$").gsub("*", "?").gsub("PeRc", "%"))
      result = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com',"/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/ProgrammeIDByName?call=SingleChannelIDByName&apikey=a4d2f0d23dcc84ce983ff9157f8b7f88&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&programmename=#{programename}&mode=getProgrammeid&pageno=1&userid=-1"))
      if result["getprogrammeidbyname"]
        result = result["getprogrammeidbyname"]["programmeidbyname"]["programmeid"]
        @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/FullProgrammeDetail?call=FullProgrammeDetail&apikey=74071a673307ca7459bcf75fbd024e09&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&pageno=1&programmeimagesize=large&channelimagesize=large&imagesize=large&programmeid=#{result}&starttime=&mode=fullProgrammeDetail&userid=-1"))
        @similarprogrames = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/SimilarProgramme?call=SimilarProgramme&apikey=950a4152c2b4aa3ad78bdd6b366cc179&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&programmeimagesize=large&channelimagesize=large&imagesize=large&programmeid=#{result}&mode=similarProgrammes&userid=-1"))
        @castandcrew =  JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/ProgramCastAndCrew?call=ProgramCastAndCrew&apikey=c3c59e5f8b3e9753913f4d435b53c308&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&pageno=1&programmeid=#{result}&mode=castNcrew&userid=-1"))
        @webvideos =  JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/WebVideos?call=WebVideos&apikey=9461cce28ebe3e76fb4b931c35a169b0&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&imagesize=large&programmeid=#{result}&mode=webVideos&userid=-1"))
        @nextschedule =  JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/MoreProgrammeSchedule?call=MoreProgrammeSchedule&apikey=758874998f5bd0c393da094e1967a72b&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&channelimagesize=large&programmeid=#{result}&mode=nextSchedule&userid=-1"))
        @programename =   CGI::unescape(programename)
      else
        @data = {}
        @programename =   CGI::unescape(programename)
      end

      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] =~ /\/channel(.*)/
      channelname = CGI::escape(params['_escaped_fragment_'].split("/").last.gsub(/CeNc/,"$#*!").gsub(/DqO/, '"').gsub(/PLus/, '+').gsub(/ObR/, '[').gsub(/CbR/, ']').gsub(/AtR/, '@').gsub(/EmPe/, '&').gsub(/HaSh/, '#').gsub(/StAr/, '*').gsub("-", " ").gsub("~", "-").gsub("$", "/").gsub(/DoLr/, "$").gsub("*", "?").gsub("PeRc", "%"))
      result = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/SingleChannelIDByName?call=SingleChannelIDByName&apikey=6a61d423d02a1c56250dc23ae7ff12f3&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&channelname=#{channelname}&mode=getChannelid&pageno=1"))
      if result["getsinglechannelidbyname"]
        result = result["getsinglechannelidbyname"]["singlechannelidbyname"]["channelid"]
        @data = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/SingleChannelDetail?call=SingleChannelDetail&apikey=352fe25daf686bdb4edca223c921acea&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&channelimagesize=large&channelid=#{result}&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website;ipaddress=127.0.0.1;useragent=Mozilla/5.0+(X11,+Linux+i686)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/28.0.1500.95+Safari/537.36&mode=channelDetails"))
        @similarchannels = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/SimilarChannels?call=SimilarChannels&apikey=839ab46820b524afda05122893c2fe8e&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&pageno=1&context=custid=1;msisdn=222;headendid=2645;applicationname=website&channelimagesize=large&imagesize=large&channelid=#{result}&mode=similarChannels"))
        @toprated =  JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/TopProgrammeForChannel?call=TopProgrammeForChannel&apikey=f90f2aca5c640289d0a29417bcb63a37&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English&context=custid%3D1%3Bmsisdn%3D222%3Bheadendid%3D2645%3Bapplicationname%3Dwebsite&pageno=1&programmeimagesize=large&channelimagesize=large&imagesize=large&channelid=#{result}&languagename=English&hybridgenre=All&mode=channelPopularPrograms"))
        @browse =   JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get('services.whatsonindia.com', "/UserStar/UserStarHost.svc/ChannelBrowsedProgrammes?call=ChannelBrowsedProgrammes&apikey=98d6f58ab0dafbb86b083a001561bb34&context=custid%3D1%3Bmsisdn%3D222%3Bheadendid%3D2645%3Bapplicationname%3Dwebsite&headendid=2645&userid=196878&channelid=#{result}&imagesize=large&pageno=1&hybridgenre=All&mode=getBrowseForChannel&responseformat=json&responselanguage=English"))
        @channelname =  CGI::unescape(channelname)
      else
        @data = {}
        @channelname =   CGI::unescape(channelname)
      end

      render :layout => false
      return false
    elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == "/Search/"
      render :layout => false
      return false
    end

    unless session[:pki]
      @alg = "AES-256-CBC"
      aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(@alg)
      aes.encrypt
      key = aes.random_key
      @pki = Base64.encode64(key).gsub(/\n/, '')
      session[:pki] = @pki
      session[:key] = key
    end
  end

  def getkey
    render :layout => false
  end


end
```

The point where it crashed is not showing any error. I don't know why this is happening and why did it take place after almost a week of going live?

Comment: Show your `index_controller.rb` file content. What is the error message (from your log file above error backtrace)?

Comment: @MarekLipka There is no error of such..The point where it crashed is
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/webuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@woi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'..in the log file

Comment: Show your `index_controller.rb` content.

Comment: @MarekLipka..I have updated the question

Comment: You probably dont have a view file named `getkey.html.erb`

Comment: @Santosh Sorry I do have a getkey.html.erb..Sorry again..I thought getkey.rb

Comment: @MarekLipka Any idea about this

Comment: What's the purpose of this `getkey` method?

Comment: @MarekLipka It is mostly for seo perspective..Not more of functionality based..It is a template

Comment: This log definitely shows ActionView looking for a view template for the `getkey` action and not finding it.  Is the `getkey` action invoked frequently? I'd start by forcing a bunch of `getkey` requests and explore from there.  Does the log show the same failure point each time one of the random crashes occurs?

Comment: @Gene Actually I had made a template for getkey event ..I dont know why it is not getting the template.But will try out your solution..Another strange thing is that this is happening every since i have migrated from 32bit Vm to 64 bit Vm..Now currently deployed on 32 bit and working fine..Dont Know how..Any idea

Comment: Well, there are only a few possibilities: a bug in your code, a bug in Rails, a bug in the OS, a virtual machine bug, or a hardware problem.  You won't be able to narrow the field until you can reliably cause the bug.  That's why I asked if it's always this `getkey` action that appears in the stack trace after these random crashes.  Or does the stack trace vary?  If it varies, you can mostly (not entirely) rule out a bug in your code and move on to the other possibilities.  I suggested hitting the `getkey` action as a way to see if calling it reliably produces the bug or only intermittently.

Comment: @Gene Ok will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the above scenario..Thought it would be helpful to someone else in the future.

I was having an config file which was giving the error and when I removed the config file The site started to run properly on the V.M.

Also it is recommended to check the configurations files for ruby application properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you set key in config/initializers/secret_token.rb? Like shown below

*

```
#{YOURAPPLIACTION_NAME}::Application.config.secret_token = #{YOUR LONG SECRET TOKEN}
```

*

Comment: Yes I have..But what is the importance of the above code and how does it matter.

Answer (score 0):

We had crashes every few days, no hints in logs. It turned out to be bad memory chips and after replacing them everything worked smoothly.

Comment: how do i check for bad memory chips,whether they are present or not

Comment: Usually the crash without log messages is a good indicator. You can do a memtest, but if the crash is only every few days it might take long to get results. We just asked the hoster to replace the chips and they did.